# What is the nullspace of 2 side by side invertible square matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is an invertible $4\times4$ matrix and $B = [ A \  A ]$.  What is the null space of the $4\times8$ matrix $B$?

I do not understand the answer, which is "all vectors $x = [ y, -y]$ for $y$ in $R_4$. I would appreciate it if someone could explain how this works.

Comment: Did you try some examples? That will help. Also, please typeset your posts with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/742).

Answer (score 0):

"Concatenating" the two relationships

$AV=\lambda V$ and $(-A)V=\lambda(-V)$.

You get : $[AV,(-A)V]=[\lambda V,\lambda(-V)]$

finally giving your relationship

$$[A,(-A)]V=\lambda[V,(-V)]$$

I understand why you have problems with the comma notation because it hasn't the same meaning on the LHS and on the RHS:

- on the left hand side, it means an horizontal concatenation whereas,
- on the right hand side, $[V,-V]$ has to be considered as a vertical concatenation, i.e., gives a $8 \times 1$ matrix (column vector) in order to have compatible dimensions.

Comment: Any comment ?... This site is based on dialog...